# Amazon SES 403 Forbidden SignatureDoesNotMatch using Laravel 5.3

Tags: amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, amazon-ses

I am using Laravel 5.3, EC2 and SES to send emails.

config/mail.php

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
```

.env has

```
MAIL_DRIVER=ses
MAIL_HOST=email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=TLS
SES_KEY='AKIA------DZQ5TYQ'
SES_SECRET=AhN8d----------------ZbBq7TNBmhNnosfYbasg6Q
SES_REGION='us-west-2'
```

composer.json

```
"require": {
    "aws/aws-sdk-php": "~3.0", 
}
```

EC2 is hosted in Mumbai and SES in us-west. I have tried the following :
1) Creating new IAM user and using the new key/secret.
2) Creating root user key/secret.
3) Running NTPDATE command.
4) php artisan cache:clear , config:clear, view:clear, dump-autoload
5) I also used sparkpost in .env and that gives error 403:forbidden too.

I am still seeing the following error :

```
[2017-05-26 06:02:00] local.ERROR: exception 'Aws\Ses\Exception\SesException' with message 'Error executing "SendRawEmail" on "https://email.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://email.us-west-2.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>SignatureDo (truncated...)
 SignatureDoesNotMatch (client): The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.
```

Full error here : https://pastebin.com/KSJinB1E

Comment: This might be of some help. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-credentials.html
>> Your SMTP user name and password are not the same as your AWS access key ID and secret access key. Do not attempt to use your AWS credentials to authenticate yourself against the SMTP endpoint.
Just want to make sure you tried this.

Comment: Yes. This is done. I am using IAM credentials. Please check SES_KEY and SES_SECRET. That's the IAM user's credentials.

Comment: You've mentioned you ran ntpdate, but not the output? Are you sure you don't have clock skew? What is the output of ntpstat?

Comment: Hi @Robo . THanks for the reply! 

$ sudo ntpdate -u ntp.ubuntu.com
28 May 07:01:54 ntpdate[9904]: adjust time server 91.189.89.199 offset 0.000914 sec

$ sudo ntpstat
Unable to talk to NTP daemon. Is it running?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53514640/3851585

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not familiar with Laravel to begin with. However, if you are using SMTP, you need to specify `MAIL_USERNAME` and `MAIL_PASSWORD`. Also the driver should be `SMTP` and not `SES` since you are using SMTP host of SES.

The documentation link - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-credentials.html should provide you with ways to generate SMTP credentials which are different from your AWS IAM credentials.

In short, you are not using **SES SDK** but **SMTP** to send emails. So SES_KEY and SES_SECRET won't do.

Comment: you dont need smtp username/password, just using key and secret should get u login ses in laravel...

Answer (score 3):

1) check your server or local machine's **"Date & time"** up to date or not.

2) check config/mail.php with below

```
'driver'    => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'ses'),
'host'      => env('MAIL_HOST'),
'port'      => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
'encryption'=> env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
'username'  => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
'password'  => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
'sendmail'  => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
```

3) check your .env file with below

```
MAIL_DRIVER=ses
MAIL_HOST=email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=[your AMI KEY]
MAIL_PASSWORD=[your AMI SECRET]
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

4) check your Config/Services.php file with below

```
'ses' => [
    'key' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
    'secret' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
    'region' => 'us-east-1',// change to your AWS region
],
```

***Don't use amazon ses smtp credentials as MAIL_USERNAME & MAIL_PASSWORD***

Comment: Your note at the end about NOT using the SES user credentials was exactly what I needed... manually creating a new user with the same permissions and using those credentials resolved my issue

Answer (score 2):

I was using the *'ses'* `MAIL_DRIVER` in laravel too and had the exact same problem as the OP. The issue for me was the IAM user I was using - I used the one that the SES wizard created for me which worked for a while, but then stopped. All I had to do to fix it, was create a new *'Programmatic access'* IAM user with the `"ses:SendRawEmail"` permission and emails started flowing.

Comment: i also had to check the "AWS Management Console access" so that i can get the username and password. so the following .env settings worked for me:

```
    MAIL_USERNAME=[IAM USERNAME]
    MAIL_PASSWORD=[IAM PASSWORD]
    SES_KEY=[SMTP USERNAME]
    SES_SECRET=[SMTP PASSWORD]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need SMTP username/password, just using IAM key and secret should get u login SES in Laravel...

You seems put necessary quotation marks in key and region, they should be:

```
SES_KEY=AKIA------DZQ5TYQ
SES_SECRET=AhN8d----------------ZbBq7TNBmhNnosfYbasg6Q
SES_REGION=us-west-2
```

If that's not the case, make sure your IAM user has **SES write** permission:
[image: AWS IAM user for SES]

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to specify the same email address in the .env file the same one which was verified in Amazon SES.