# Laravel AWS Simple Email Service Error SignatureDoesNotMatch (client): The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided.

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, email, laravel-5.5, amazon-ses

I m using aws ses in laravel 5.5, when i send mail using aws ses driver error occur like below---

```
Error executing "SendRawEmail" on "https://email.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://email.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:\n
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/">\n
  <Error>\n
    <Type>Sender</Type>\n
    <Code>SignatureDo (truncated...)\n
 SignatureDoesNotMatch (client): The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details. - <ErrorResponse xmlns="http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/">\n
  <Error>\n
    <Type>Sender</Type>\n
    <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>\n
    <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.</Message>\n
  </Error>\n
  <RequestId>4985867a-7067-11e8-afe4-1b9673bed905</RequestId>\n
</ErrorResponse>\n
```

My Controller:

```
$sendemail = Mail::send('emails.sendmail',$maildetails,function($message) use($maildetails){
                                                        $message->to($maildetails->email)->subject('Mail Sending process');
                                                  });
```

My Env File:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=ses
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=****@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

SES_ACCESS_KEY =ALKILJUYRTHNFGREDFDSW
SES_ACCESS_SECRET=kjkdcghcbhjghgfrtywuiueiyeuhevgh+cschujhj-jyt
SES_REGION =eu-west-1
```

My Service.php FILE:

```
'ses' => [
        'key' => env('SES_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('SES_ACCESS_SECRET'),
        'region' => env('SES_REGION'),
    ],
```

My Composer.json File:

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=7.0.0",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.59",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
        "laravel/passport": "~4.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0"

    },
```

I think done my aws ses configuration process correctly,but i cant't understand why its not working. if any one have a solution for this...?

Comment: I hope those are not your real access key and secret.

Comment: no these access key and secret is working fine in core php file,but its not working only in laravel ses configuration...

Comment: I mean you shouldn't reveal your access key and secret to the world

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53514640/3851585

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you've followed the "Create My SMTP Credentials" process in AWS Console > SES (rather than creating an IAM user and manually assigning roles/permissions). If not, try that before continuing.

Next, rather than using the `ses` driver try the `smtp` one.

Adding these lines to your `.env` file should work:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
MAIL_USERNAME="insert_iam_key"
MAIL_PASSWORD="insert_iam_secret"
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="no-reply@example.com"
```

**NOTE**: If SES is still in sandbox mode (ie. you have not requested a rate limit increase yet), make sure the domain you're sending from and the email address you're sending to has been verified in AWS Console > SES.